# MySQL COUNT value as a column

Tags: mysql, count

I have two tables

```
BOOK(book_id, book_name)
```

and

```
COPY(copy_id, book_id, available(bool))
```

I want to have a query to display book_id, book_name, and COUNT(*) of all copies with the same book_id in COPY table that have available set to true. Sample query output should look like this:

```
1, BookA, 2
2, BookB, 4
3, BookC, 0
```

So BookA has two COPY tuples with available set to true. This is what I have so far, it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM BOOK)book,
(SELECT book_id, COUNT(copy_id) FROM COPY)copy
WHERE book.book_id = copy.book_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since bool values are `1` if `true` in MySQL, you can sum them up

```
SELECT b.book_id, 
       b.book_name, 
       sum(c.available) as copy_count
FROM book b
left outer join copy c on c.book_id = b.book_id
group by b.book_id
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81ed2/1)

Comment: Good query for the case that copy id is an ID and it is unique.

Comment: This one doesn't display my third case in which BookC has 0 COUNT of available.

Comment: try changing `sum(c.available)` to `sum(ifnull(c.available,0))`. (although @juergend seems to be right)

Comment: Inner joins only display rows when they match in both tables. Outer joins will always display from one regardless of a match in the other.

Comment: @user1795609: See [this very good join explanation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variant:

```
SELECT b.book_id, 
       b.book_name, 
       count(c.available) as copy_count
FROM book b
left outer join copy c on c.book_id = b.book_id and c.available = 1
group by b.book_id
```

This is a little more efficient because the join doesn't include any of the rows with unavailable books, so it's a smaller intermediate table to process.